# Different graphic cards drivers while booting from external media

Tags: linux, xorg, amd-graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I am booting a certain system of mine with ubuntu 9.10 from external HDD. I am satisfied with the setup and it works fine, however I would like to modify it so that I can choose which graphic card drivers to load during the boot time. Specifically I would like to choose between:

- nvidia proprietary driver
- ati proprietary driver
- generic driver

Currently if I am using proprietary drivers then dont boot into X, delete xorg.conf, start gdm and reconfigure the system using jockey (for hardware drivers).

What would be the steps to make this (semi-)automatic and avoid restarting X?

Where could one find examples of such scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make 3 different grub entries for
   each kernel with `driver1`, `driver2`,
   `driver3` as options.
2. Make 3  different xorg.conf (each with one of the three drivers) and name them `xorg.conf1`, `xorg.conf2`, `xorg.conf2`.
3. Write initscript that executes before X that greps `/proc/cmdline` for `driver1`, `driver2` oder `driver3` and then symlinks `xorg.conf1`, `xorg.conf2` or `xorg.conf2` to `xorg.conf`

I've done something similar to switch between dualheaded and not-dualheaded screensetup in the times before xrandr. Unfortunately the scripts and the documentation is long gone.

Possible improvements:

- use udev-rules
- let the initscript auto-detect the current graphics card

Comment: +1 seems the right path. How would you auto-detect? (lspci then insmod?)

Comment: lspci is difficult... Sometimes graphics cards are "Display controller", sometimes they are called "VGA Controller". First thing that came to my mind was "lshw". For example: "lshw | grep -m1 -A5 display | grep vendor" or "lshw -c display | grep vendor"

Answer (score 1):

You could always make a shell script that automates that process for you.

Comment: Yes, I would do that, but I am not sure what are all the steps. I do have two different xorg.conf files, but is that enough? should I be also doing some insmods prior to starting gdm?

Comment: X should load any modules defined in the config file.

Comment: As Lego399 suggested you can run a script that can load different Xorg config files. Just prepare those config files (xorg.conf.nv, xorg.conf.ati, xorg.conf.vesa) and copy one of them in the xorg.conf original file. After that you can run Xorg server. So you should put this script before gdm starts (or another login manager).

Comment: @Pier, actually that was what I did (I have two working xorg.conf files, one for each hardware setup), but that was not enough. I assume that was not enough, as I have to re-run jockey to make things work.

Answer (score 1):

The following might provide some hints at possibly achieving what you want via grub:

http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Framebuffer

Answer (score 1):

Create different versions of your xorg.conf based on the stuff you want. Say:

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.nvidia
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.ati
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.generic
```

Then configure multiple boot configurations in /boot/grub/grub.cfg and put a different kernel parameter (e.g. xconfig=myconfig) in every line where the kernel is specified. Somewhere along the lines of:

```
menuentry "Ubuntu, Linux 2.6.31-17 nvidia" {
  ...
  linux   /vmlinuz-2.6.31-17 root=UUID=885a6a07-fd6c-4638-aa17-d38997d477e1 xconfig=nvidia ro single
 ...
} 

menuentry "Ubuntu, Linux 2.6.31-17 ati" {
  ...
  linux   /vmlinuz-2.6.31-17 root=UUID=885a6a07-fd6c-4638-aa17-d38997d477e1 xconfig=ati ro single
 ...
}

menuentry "Ubuntu, Linux 2.6.31-17 generic" {
  ...
  linux   /vmlinuz-2.6.31-17 root=UUID=885a6a07-fd6c-4638-aa17-d38997d477e1 xconfig=generic ro single
 ...
}
```

Kernel parameters that aren't recognized are ignored, but will still be available in /proc/cmdline. Based on this, you can write a small shell script that chooses the correct config file:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f /etc/X11/xorg.conf
config=`cat /proc/cmdline |sed -e 's/.*xconfig=\([a-z]*\).*/\1/g'
ln -s /etc/X11/xonfig.conf.$config /etc/X11/xconfig.conf
```

Then put this somewhere in your boot order, before gdm starts.

Comment: Oops.. I kind of read the question wrong.. anyway.. :)